# makeEwsRequestAsync Error only in Exchange 2013

Tags: exchangewebservices, office-js, outlook-web-addins

I developed an Outlook Add-in with the ability to forward and delete an email.

I use `makeEwsRequestAsync` send SOAP message to EWS.

It works on my own mailbox (I think Office 365, because my version is 15.20), I asked to my coworker, one Exchange environment in 2013 to test on another version. With this second mailbox, I have an error code `9020` with the message `Operation fail`.

Have you an idea why it’s work on my mailbox, and no on other ?

This my SOAP message:

```js
return '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>' +
        '<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"' +
        '               xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/messages"' +
        '               xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"' +
        '               xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"' +
        '               xmlns:t="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types">' +
        '  <soap:Header>' +
        '    <RequestServerVersion Version="Exchange2013" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types" soap:mustUnderstand="0" />' +
        '  </soap:Header>' +
        '  <soap:Body>' +
        '    <GetItem' +
        '                xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/messages"' +
        '                xmlns:t="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types">' +
        '      <ItemShape>' +
        '        <t:BaseShape>IdOnly</t:BaseShape>' +
        '      </ItemShape>' +
        '      <ItemIds>' +
        '        <t:ItemId Id="' + Office.context.mailbox.item.itemId + '"/>' +
        '      </ItemIds>' +
        '    </GetItem>' +
        '  </soap:Body>' +
        '</soap:Envelope>';
```

Comment: Can you take a look at the HTTP traffic during this call? That error code is rather generic but the HTTP traffic itself may shed some light on what is going on. Fiddler is an excellent tool for this.

Comment: Also can you please clarify, for the user where you see the error, are they on Office365 or on-premises Exchange (if latter, which version of Exchange server), and which client and client version they are using?

Comment: Sorry for the delay. I Start to looking for the HTTP traffic, but now the add-in works. I Don't change anything so I don't know why sometime the add-in didn't work. There is a pattern maybe to retry the request when there is an error and give up when the error come from many time ? The error was only in Exchange 2013 with Outlook ProPlus.

Comment: Good to hear that it works now.